# lunching jade IPMS inter-plaform agent migration in ubuntu 10.04

Tags: java, migration, ubuntu-10.04, agents-jade

I have a trouble with [JADE](http://jade.tilab.com/) IPMS inter-platform agent migration in Ubuntu 10.04. When I lunch jade with command >java -cp lib/jade.jar;lib/migration.jar jade.Boot -gui -platform-id Platform1 services jade.core.mobility.AgentMobilityAgent;jade.core.migratio.InterPlatformMobilityService -accept-foreign-agents true . The error is :

```
lib/migration.jar: line 1: PK: command not found
lib/migration.jar: line 2: META-INF/��PK: No such file or directory
K-*��ϳR0�3��r�Cq,HL�HU�%���_^jMETA-INF/MANIFEST.MF�M��LK-.
                            y���RKRSt�*A�M�
�u�
   L4�K�|3����+�KRs�<���4y�x�PK
N<accs/PK
N<
  accs/client/PK
N<fipa/PK
N<
  fipa/agents/PK
N<  fipa/api/PK
N<
fipa/jade/PK
N<fipa/jade/compat/PK
N<fipa/launcher/PK
N<jade/PK
N<
jade/core/PK
N<jade/core/launcher/PK
```

I lunch the same command in window successfully, but ubuntu is failed.I am a newbie in Jade Programming ,Please help me,Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, classpath is separated with `:`, not `;`, which splits commands.